# Multiple window WPF application: Sending values and sharing data

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF and have currently set up a 1 window WPF.
Now however I need a new window to share a Dictionary  clientData;
When I click the entry in a ListBox in the main window I need to pass the entryId to the new window that can acces the clientData[entryId].

I've always made single window apps in the past so again I'm new to this.

How is this done?

Comment: Make both windows use the same view model.

Comment: View Model? Is it possible to create a new instance of the window class and access it? :)

Comment: WPF applications are usually built using the MVVM (Model-View-View Model) design pattern. Recommend you get a book like Programming WPF.

Comment: If you don't use a view model, then pass the current window to the second window and let the second window call methods on the first one to update it (or set properties). Usually, this is what a view model is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally there are two easy possibilities to communicate between two windows.

Possibility 1:
You create `public` and `static` variables in both windows like this:

```
    public static int Property1 { get; set; }
```

Possibility 2:
You create a parameterized method to show your subwindow and return your variables as `public` like this:

```
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
    public void ShowThis(int parameter)//Gets called by your MainWindow
    {
        this.Property2 = parameter;
        this.Show();
    }
```

**EDIT**

Based to your problem:

Your subwindow:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ShowThis<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        listBox.Items.Clear();
        foreach(var item in data)
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(item);
        }
        this.Show();
    }
}
```

And your MainWindow would look like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Window1 window1;//your subwindow
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        window1 = new Window1();
    }

    private void buttonShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//button to show subwindow
    {
        int[] testData = new int[5] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
        window1.ShowThis(testData);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I need to set the ListBox of the second window not the first?

Comment: I inserted the Window1 class after the main window class and get the error: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS0103 The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context .

Comment: In which way did you added Window1?

Comment: Right after the definition of the main window in the code behind file?

Comment: You need to add your window in this way: Projects --> Add Window